# Magento: unset a second/third level block from layout?

Tags: magento

How to unset a child/grandchild block from the layout ?

For example from

```
<reference name="content">
            <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
                   <block type="catalog/product_view_media" name="product.info.media" as="media" template="catalog/product/view/media.phtml"/>
            </block>
</reference>
```

I can remove the whole

```
<reference name="content">
    <action method="unsetChild"><name>product.info</name></action>
</reference>
```

but I want to remove only name="product.info.media"  from "product.info", not the whole product.info .

How to do this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To move a child block from one parent to another, reference the direct parent, call unsetChild on it, and then use the insert method to assign the block instance as child to a different parent.

```
<reference name="product.info">
    <!-- use the alias here -->
    <action method="unsetChild"><child>media</child></action>
</reference>
<reference name="new.parent">
    <!-- use the full block name here -->
    <action method="insert"><child>product.info.media</child></action>
</reference>
```

Unseting grandchild blocks is not supported, I don't think thats stupid but sensible (because where would you stop - unsetGrandGrandGrandChild()?).

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
<reference name="product.info">
    <action method="unsetChild"><name>product.info.media</name></action>
</reference>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the block is added through a layout file (not by code) then you can prevent it ever being set with;

```
<remove name="product.info.media" />
```

Comment: Yes, the block is added from base/default/layout/catalog.xml  but i dont want to remove the subblock alltogether, i want to move it under another block, hence the unsetChild. Granted I am new to magento, but it seems stupid to only be able to unset direct children and not subchildren.

Comment: You can still create a new block with the same type and template and even name in the new location.